# How to use Pagination | CodeIgniter |

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I have a query to show all users on my webpage.
We have around 327 users. and i want to use pagination. but i cant find out how i can use this in my own code.

This is my Controller

```
<?php


class alluser extends MY_Controller {



    function __construct() {


        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('date');

        $this->load->helper('file');

        $this->load->helper('dir');

        $this->load->model('user_model');

        $this->load->model('inspiration_model');

        $this->load->model('notes_model');

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['total_rows'] = 300;
        $config['per_page'] = 20;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        echo $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->data['head']['stylesheets'][] = 'onestowatch/onestowatch.min.css';

        $this->data['head']['javascripts'][] = 'shuffle/jquery.shuffleLetters.min.js';

        $this->data['head']['javascripts'][] = 'custom/app/onestowatch.min.js';

        if (!logged_in()) {

            redirect('login');

        }

    }


   public function index(){

    $user_id = $this->data['user']['user_id'];

    $now = time();



    $designments = $this->user_model->get_my_running_designments_by_id($user_id, $now);



    foreach ($designments as &$designment) {

        $designment['inspiration_count'] = $this->inspiration_model->get_inspiration_count_for_user_by_id($designment['designment_id'], $user_id);

        $designment['note_count'] = $this->notes_model->get_notes_count_for_user_by_id($designment['designment_id'], $user_id);

    }



    $this->data['my_designments'] = $designments;



    $this->data['user_info'] = $this->user_model->get_user_info_by_user_id($user_id);

    $this->data['user_info']['user_icon'] = $this->user_model->get_big_user_icon_by_id($user_id);

    $this->data['onestowatch'] = $this->user_model->get_ones_to_watch(1000);

    $this->template->load('templates/template_view', 'app/alluser/view', $this->data);

}
```

This is my View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onestowatch = <?= json_encode($onestowatch) ?>;
</script>

<section id="list" class="w940 fl">
    <p class="clearfix"><span class="bg-white ff-b orange f28 title-1 fl shadow">All users</span></p>
</section>


<script type="text/x-mustache" id="onetowatch">
    <dl style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <dd>
    <div class="onetowatch shadow">
    <img class="user_icon" src="<?= site_url('') ?>{{image}}">
    <div class="fl ff-l f18 shuffle">{{fullname}}</div>
    </div>
    </dd>
    </dl>
</script>
```

And model query:

```
function get_ones_to_watch($limit, $smallicon = false) {
        $this->db->select('user_to_designment.user_id, count(user_to_designment.user_id) as designment_joined, user_profiles.first_name, user_profiles.middle_name, user_profiles.last_name, user_profiles.date_of_birth');
        $this->db->from('user_to_designment');
        $this->db->join('user_to_user_profile', 'user_to_designment.user_id = user_to_user_profile.user_id');
        $this->db->join('user_profiles', 'user_to_user_profile.profile_id = user_profiles.profile_id');
        $this->db->group_by('user_id');
        $this->db->order_by('designment_joined', 'desc');
        $this->db->limit($limit);

        $onestowatch = $this->db->get()->result_array();

        foreach ($onestowatch as &$onetowatch) {
            if($smallicon){
                $onetowatch['image'] = self::get_small_user_icon_by_id($onetowatch['user_id']);
            }else{
                $onetowatch['image'] = self::get_big_user_icon_by_id($onetowatch['user_id']);
            }
        }

        return $onestowatch;
    }
```

Thanks for every help i will get !

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below link to create pagination
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: I have wrote tutorial about Cdeigniter Pagination. Please have a look and give your suggestions https://www.cloudways.com/blog/pagination-in-codeigniter/